# both IPV4 and IPV6 at the same time over DSL connection?

Tags: networking, ipv6

Let me describe the situation:

When I connect the computer with the wire, I get an IPV6 address automatically, there's a "Wired connection" tab in network manager, and I can access a website that supports IPV6 (google, facebook, etc.) **with a hosts file**, or use the proxy like *google.com.sixxs.org*

But if I want to access the whole internet, I have to create a **DSL connection** with username and password that ISP gave me. However, after I change my connection into this DSL connection, I cannot access websites over IPV6, even there's the site's ipv6 address in `/etc/hosts`, then I realize that I lose my IPV6 connection because the **ping6** says `connect: Network is unreachable`.

The problem is, there's no IPV6 tab or options about IPV6 in the configure of the DSL connection. It feels like I can only use one connection at the same time, but the DSL doesn't support IPV6 and the `wired connection` doesn't support IPV4(I mean, there's no way to input the password the ISP gave me)

When I use another computer with MS windows, in the same environment, there's no such problem, I can access both V4 and V6 at the same time.

So how to solve this? thanks a lot.

I'm in 11.10 + gnome3

Comment: xDSL connection is IP agnostic.  But you should have a router either connected to the xDSL modem or built into the modem.  That router has to support IPv6. Newer MS Windows sets up a tunnel if no IPv6 and only IPv4. I would like to have some data about your net.  Like `ip add show`, `ip -6 route show`, `ip neigh show` and `ip madd show`.  And you should update your Ubuntu OS to at least 14.04 LTS or 14.11.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the connection manager(Network Connections). Select the Wired tab. Click on your connection and click edit. Under the IPv4 tab, select Manual. Your settings will be as follows:

1)Addresses: I recommend 192.168.1.99, if that does not work, use 192.168.0.99

2)DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 (Google's recursive DNS)

3)Search domains: example.com

4)Click Save. Now you should have both IPv4 and IPv6.

If you need to, disconnect and reconnect, or reboot.

Comment: well...but, where should I input the username and password that ISP  gave me?

Comment: @namiheike if you have a modem, you give the username/password to the modem. If not, than you do not even need those credentials as you can already connect via IPv6, which means you are allowed to connect in the first place.

Comment: without username and password, how can I access the whole internet via ipv4, I mean, not all sites support v6, right?

Comment: Is it allowing you to connect at all to IPv4 without the password?

Comment: no, just v6 supported sites.

Comment: @namiheike Who is your ISP and how do you get your IPv6 connection? Anther  link? Or DSL?

Comment: I got IPV6 with the default wired connection. I mean, just put wire in the plug and then got a IPV6 address

Comment: Who is your ISP? Do your ISP support your xDSL router?  That will make us look up what the ISP supports.  There are many different ways to connect to IPv6.  And as with IPv4, some need you to log in on a server at your ISP to grant you access.

Answer (score 0):

For your point #2, the IPv6 network may be unreachable because it is blocked by the firewall. See if setting "IPV6=yes" in /etc/ufw/ufw.conf helps.